# Laravel - Cron Jobs On Windows

Tags: php, cron, laravel, laravel-4

I added this to the framework: `'liebig/cron'`.

I added that code to the routes.php:

```
Route::get('/cron/run/c68pd2s4e363221a3064e8807da20s1sf', function () {
    Cron::add('example1', '* * * * *', function() {
        $u = User::find(5);
        $u->fullname = time();
        $u->save();
    });
    $report = Cron::run();
    print_r ($report);
});
```

That page will be: `http://localhost:8000/cron/run/c68pd2s4e363221a3064e8807da20s1sf`.

I tried to make cron jobs by the Task Scheduler, I did it to `'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/php.exe' with argument 'localhost:8000/cron/run/c68pd2s4e363221a3064e8807da20s1sf'` but it didn't worked.

The only way it working it using chrome:
`'C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' with argument 'http://localhost:8000/cron/run/c68pd2s4e363221a3064e8807da20s1sf'`

But I don't want it, I want it would be running by php and without opening every minute the chrome.

Any ideas to make that page will be running by php.exe ?

I hope you understood the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create batch file with these two lines

```
cd c:\laravel-project\
c:\php5\php.exe artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1
```

Go to Windows 10 Task Scheduler

Click Create basic task, choose When I logon trigger and then choose Start a program -> your .bat file.
Check Open properties dialog option and click Finish.
In task properties click Triggers, then click New and add new trigger Repeat task every 1 minute

Answer (score -1):

That's because you're using the wrong tool. Do you have [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/) installed? If you have you could just do a:

```
curl -i http://localhost:8000/cron/run/c68pd2s4e363221a3064e8807da20s1sf
```

Alternatively, try the ping command:

```
ping http://localhost:8000/cron/run/c68pd2s4e363221a3064e8807da20s1sf
```

Comment: And how I should make it every minute ?